# How to return to UIkit from Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

After much pain, tears and pulling out of hair I have finally managed to merge my UIKit (ARC enabled) app with my Cocos2D game project.  Basically, I have a UIKit app that has (amongst other things) a button to play the Cocos2D game.  The button calls an action which sets up the director, eaglview and scenes, etc and the game works as it should.

When you die in the game I want to automatically return to the menu with the play game button in UIKit, but I am absolutely clueless as to how to achieve this.  Any ideas?

Those of you kind enough to answer please bear in mind that I am kinda new to all this and it's fine by me if you pretend you are talking to a 5 year old.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This answer relies a LOT on the way your project is structured, like if you are using a navigation controller, etc. If you are absolutely clueless about how to do this, maybe you should be doing simpler things until you are better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how did you integrate your Cocoa Touch part with cocos2d, but did you try something like this:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] removeFromSuperview];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
// any further cleanup, according to your integration code
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  Tried your code and it just gives me a white screen.  From the UIkit part, following the button press I create a RootViewController which creates the director, EAGLView, then just the following:

[self.view addSubview:glView];
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
GameLayer *aGameLayer = [GameLayer node];
[scene addChild:aGameLayer];
    
[director runWithScene:scene];

Not sure if this helps...